# Cucumber hangs after all scenarios passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, jruby, jrubyonrails

I have jRuby on Rails application with some cucumber tests.

Problem is that `cucumber features` hangs after executing all steps until I press ctrl+c. Interesting that it only happens if all of the tests pass.

```
10 scenarios (10 passed)
116 steps (116 passed)
13m59.058s
-> hangs here
```

I've tried adding global `at_exit` hook, it is being executed and than command freezes.

Here is my `bundle list` https://gist.github.com/37f2448055071bbbc636

My temporary solution is to add `at_exit` hook like this

```
at_exit do 
  exit! !($!.nil? || $!.is_a?(SystemExit) && $!.success?)
end
```

Some connections may be left opened, data not cleaned, etc. but it will at least exit with correct status code, which is used by CI server.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a very old post, but in case anyone stumbles upon this, per:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#exiting

if you add `--exit` after your cucumber command, cucumber will exit when the test are finished. This is what worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we realized that this lock-up happens when we created background processes that weren't quitting properly.  We fixed this be replacing `system()` calls with `spawn()` ones, and killing any child processes in our at_exit hook.